# Was there any restriction on private citizens owning cannons and other large weaponry in 17th, 18th and 19th century Europe?

Tags: europe, 19th-century, law, 18th-century, 17th-century

Were there laws limiting what kind of guns a private citizen in Europe could own? Could John Doe go to a shop and commission a cannon to be made for his own personal use?

Comment: "Europe" is a whole lot of countries with separate laws. Making cannon has always been expensive, so acquiring a military surplus one is more plausible.

Comment: Not only is Europe a big place but 300 years is a long, long time too. The question is too broad as currently written.

Comment: Many Merchant ships had at least one naval cannon lasting well into the 19th century at least.  These ships were owned by large corporations like the East India companies, and by small groups of part owners, and by single persons in some cases.  Thus private persons could acquire ownership of cannons in those centuries.  Licensed privateers owned cannons. Pirate crews also acquired cannons, probably mostly illegally.